# How to upload images for ruby on rails app using paperclip gem onto IBM Bluemix Object Storage using S3 API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, paperclip, object-storage

I have been using the tutorial:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3 
For adding images to S3 storage on AWS, but now want to use IBM's Object Storage which supports S3 API (using gem 'aws-sdk').

**Using below:**

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('REGION'),
    }
  }
```

where `REGION = 'us-geo'`

**gives the error**

`Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (Failed to open TCP connection to david-provest-movies.s3.us-geo.amazonaws.com:443 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)).`

---

How would I change the 'david-provest-movies.s3.us-geo.amazonaws.com:443' to the desired 'david-provest-movies.s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net' URL?

**Link to the API:**
https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/cloud-object-storage-s3-api-intro/

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid region for s3.

- us-east-2
- us-west-1
- us-west-2
- ca-central-1
- ap-south-1
- ap-northeast-2
- ap-southeast-1
- ap-southeast-2
- ap-northeast-1
- eu-central-1
- eu-west-1
- eu-west-2
- sa-east-1

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Here is bluemix

Note: Using third-party tools or SDKs may enforce setting a ‘LocationConstraint’ when creating a bucket. If required, this value must be set to ‘us-standard’. Unlike AWS S3, IBM COS uses this value to indicate the storage class of an object. This field has no relation to physical geography or region - those values are provided within the endpoint used to connect to the service. Currently, the only permitted values for ‘LocationCostraint’ are ‘us-standard’, ‘us-vault’, ‘us-cold’, ‘us-flex’, ‘us-south-standard’, ‘us-south-vault’, us-south-cold’, and ‘us-south-flex’.

Comment: Yes thanks, it is a valid IBM Bluemix region not a AWS. I want to change the URL to point to the IBM Bluemix path of 'objectstorage.softlayer.net' which is their object storage path.

Comment: I didn't see part, sorry. I don't know much about in bluemix.

Comment: Most of the time when I see that error in the AWS sdk is a public resource doesn't exist, the url is not right or the instance desnt have dns resolution.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I think there should be an s3 credential key that can change the URl. But I just don't know what it is.

Comment: The region in their example had region: "us-standard",
endpoint: 's3-api.us-geo.objectstorage

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried to use paperclip yet, but the issue here is that the IBM Cloud endpoint needs to be specified.  I'll take a closer look at the paperclip docs, but it looks like something along the lines of specifying the bucket URL (where {bucket-name} is hard coded in the below snippet but could be constructed) or some other method to explicitly specify the host name or root URL.  There's a chance that paperclip has the AWS endpoint hardcoded and the team at IBM will need to contribute a method for setting a custom endpoint ([which is fully supported in the `aws-sdk` gem when creating clients](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html)).

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('REGION'),
      bucket_url: 'https://{bucket-name}.s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net'
    }
  }
```

Let me know if it seems like using an explicit bucket URL doesn't work, and I'll look into whether the endpoint is hardcoded in paperclip and what we can do to fix it.